# Angularjs moving logic from the controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

How can I move this function from the controller into a separate file?

It might be a simple question but I tried to do that with services and factories but I keep doing something wrong regarding dependency injection or the syntax of the service or factory.

This is the controller:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('myAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    (function() {
        //the function to be moved
        //do somthing
    })();

    $scope.data = {};

    $http.//......do something else

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/dpqu0axh/6/): (Replaced real API link at request of OP)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in data.products" ng-bind="product.name"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .constant("dataUrl", "https://some-link.com")
  .controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, corsService) {
    $scope.data = {};
    corsService.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.data.products = data;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $scope.data.error = error;
    });
  });

angular.module("myApp")
  .factory('corsService', function($http, dataUrl) {
    return {
      getData: getData
    }

    function corsRequestEnabler() {
      //Enable CORS requests
    };

    function getData() {
      corsRequestEnabler();
      return $http.get(dataUrl)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('Response',  response);
          return response.data;
        }, function(error) {
          return error
        })
    }
  });
```

Comment: I need to move just the function into a service or factory. The function works right now but it is too messy.

Comment: @DanRomulus So move it into `myAppFactory` instead of `myHttpFn`?

Comment: http://pastie.org/10929423   what I am doing wrong      getting :Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: corsServiceProvider <- corsService <- myAppCtrl . So it must be how I inject the service.

Comment: do you have a few minutes to talk in chat about this?

Comment: @DanRomulus Sure, just throw me the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120110/discussion-between-dan-romulus-and-nexusduck).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var app=angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myAppCtrl', function (corsService, $scope, $http, dataUrl  )           {

corsService();


app.factory('corsService' ,function($http){

var data = {};

$http.get(dataUrl)
.success(function (data) {
    data.products = data;
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function (error) {
 data.error = error;
});
return data;
});

});
```

Comment: You've declared a new module 'myApp' instead of using the getter syntax

Comment: No you're not, the module was already created in the file for the controller. You should use `angular.module('myApp').factory....`

Comment: yes I am keep getting  [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: corsServiceProvider <- corsService <- myAppCtrl . I am keep doing smth. wrong injecting the service into the module

Comment: that's because you need to inject $http

Comment: I just need to move the function that is working the way it is but it is too messy to be in the controller. The function doesn't use any service.

Comment: yes i have updated the answer if you want to use a particular service you need to inject it. like you are injecting $http in your controller

Comment: I did that but I am keep getting the injector error : [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: keep doing smth wrong

Comment: I don't want to add the $http service into the corsService factory. I just want to add the function to be moved it to a separate .js file, inject it into my controller or main module and run it